# Error MSB4036: The "Output" task was not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'm new in C# and I have created a new project in visual studio 2010.
I build this one and I have this error in my View Error List:

> Error 1 The "Output" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The
>   name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the
>   task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly
>   declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files
>   located in the "C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"
>   directory.

And in my output view I have :

> C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1580,7):
>   error MSB4036: The "Output" task was not found. Check the following:
>   1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly
>   declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files
>   located in the "C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"
>   directory.

Can someone help me.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error today along with all of my references not being found. To fix ==> go to Program Features (Win7) click to remove and then choose repair/reinstall. You must have the original installation media available. This takes about 1-2 hours. Once complete, your projects should load correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar error after Windows10 Millenium update and resolve it by enabling .Net FrameWork 3.5 in Windows features.

[image: Windows Features .Net framework 3.5 enable]

Note that you should reboot you computer after enabling .Net 3.5.

More information about installing and enabling .Net Framework 3.5 you could find in article [Installing the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443.aspx)

> You can enable the .NET Framework 3.5 yourself through Control Panel. This option requires an Internet connection. 
>   Press the Windows key  on your keyboard, type Windows Features, and press Enter. This brings up the Turn Windows features on or off dialog box. Alternately, open Control Panel, click on the Programs items, and then click on “Turn Windows features on or off” under Programs and Features.
>   Select the .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0) check box, press OK, and reboot your computer if prompted.
>   You do not need to select the child items for Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) HTTP activation unless you are a developer who requires WCF script and handler mapping functionality.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: @pableiros, that you for advice. I have changed my reply. Hope that now formatting is ok.